# Can I get geom_smooth() to allow line breaks when there are NA values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I'm hoping to find a way to for line breaks to show up while using geom_smooth() - is this possible?

Here's sample data and code I'm using and the resulting plot:

```
game_number <- c(1:52)

toi <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.4, 20.2, 19.4, 18.6, 17.8, 17.1, 17.7, 17.3, 16.8, 17.1, 17.8, 17.3, 16.6,
        16.9, 17.4, 16.9, 16.1, 16.6, 16.9, 16.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16.9, 18.2, 18.5, 16.6, 16.3, 15.7, 
        15.1, 14.7, 16.5, 17.9, 16.9, NA, 17.6, 18.1, 17.9, 17.2, 18.2, 18.0, 17.3, 17.8, 18.3, 17.9)

toi_df <- tibble(player = 'Nils Lundkvist', game_number = game_number, toi = toi)
```

```
plot <- ggplot(toi_df, aes(x = game_number, y = toi, group = player, colour = player)) +
            geom_line(size = 0.6) +
            geom_smooth(se = F, size = 1) +
            scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 25), expand = c(0, 0))
```

The resulting plot looks like this. You can see the NA line breaks in in geom_line(), but the geom_smooth() line is connecting over the NA values. Is there a way to get geom_smooth() to behave like geom_line() in this scenario? Or some other ggplot command to use instead? Thank you!

[image: geom_smooth() ignoring line breaks for NA values]

Comment: This might be a hack and not apply to all data, but could you create dummy groups, then do the `geom_smooth()` using those groups and color them in the same color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest one approach where you can compute the `geom_smooth()` output in a independent dataframe and then merge with original data. Here an approach using `broom` and `tidyverse` packages:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
```

First the data:

```
#Data
game_number <- c(1:52)
toi <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.4, 20.2, 19.4, 18.6, 17.8, 17.1, 17.7, 17.3, 16.8, 17.1, 17.8, 17.3, 16.6,
         16.9, 17.4, 16.9, 16.1, 16.6, 16.9, 16.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16.9, 18.2, 18.5, 16.6, 16.3, 15.7, 
         15.1, 14.7, 16.5, 17.9, 16.9, NA, 17.6, 18.1, 17.9, 17.2, 18.2, 18.0, 17.3, 17.8, 18.3, 17.9)
toi_df <- tibble(player = 'Nils Lundkvist', game_number = game_number, toi = toi)
```

Now, we compute the smooth model:

```
#Create smooth
model <- loess(toi ~ game_number, data = toi_df)
```

We create a dataframe to save the results:

```
#Augment model output in a new dataframe
toi_df2 <- augment(model, toi_df)
```

We merge the data:

```
#Merge data
toi_df3 <- merge(toi_df,
                 toi_df2[,c("player","game_number",".fitted")],
                 by=c("player","game_number"),all.x = T)
```

Finally, we plot using `geom_line()`:

```
#Plot
ggplot(toi_df3, aes(x = game_number, y = toi, group = player, colour = player)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.6) +
  geom_line(aes(y=.fitted),size=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 25), expand = c(0, 0))
```

Output:

[image]

The approach can work if you have more than one players. In that case you can group by players (`group_by()` from `dplyr`) and using `do()` function to estimate the smooth models for each player.

**Update:**

I add a code for multi players. In this case I have created a function to iterate across groups defined by player in a list. After creating the function you have to use `split()` to get a list with each player. The function `myfunsmooth()` compute `loess`. Then, you bind the data and sketch the plot. Here the code:

The dummy data:

```
#Data
game_number <- c(1:52)
toi <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.4, 20.2, 19.4, 18.6, 17.8, 17.1, 17.7, 17.3, 16.8, 17.1, 17.8, 17.3, 16.6,
         16.9, 17.4, 16.9, 16.1, 16.6, 16.9, 16.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16.9, 18.2, 18.5, 16.6, 16.3, 15.7, 
         15.1, 14.7, 16.5, 17.9, 16.9, NA, 17.6, 18.1, 17.9, 17.2, 18.2, 18.0, 17.3, 17.8, 18.3, 17.9)
toi_df <- tibble(player = 'Nils Lundkvist', game_number = game_number, toi = toi)
toi_df0 <- tibble(player = 'Zach Ellenthal', game_number = game_number, toi = toi)
toi_df0$toi <- toi_df0$toi+15 
toi_dfm <- rbind(toi_df,toi_df0)
```

The function for `loess()`:

```
#Function for smoothing
myfunsmooth <- function(x)
{
  #Model
  model <- loess(toi ~ game_number, data = x)
  #Augment model output in a new dataframe
  y <- augment(model, x)
  #Merge data
  z <- merge(x,y[,c("player","game_number",".fitted")],
                   by=c("player","game_number"),all.x = T)
  #Return
  return(z)
}
```

Then, we create the list:

```
#Create list by player
List <- split(toi_dfm,toi_dfm$player)
```

We apply the function and bind the results in a new dataframe:

```
#Apply function
List2 <- lapply(List, myfunsmooth)
#Bind all
dfglobal <- do.call(rbind,List2)
rownames(dfglobal)<-NULL
```

Finally, we plot:

```
#Plot
ggplot(dfglobal, aes(x = game_number, y = toi, group = player, colour = player)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.6) +
  geom_line(aes(y=.fitted),size=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 45), expand = c(0, 0))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks really nice and excited to try it out. Two questions from my first attempt at it. First, getting an error assigning `toi_df2` that says `Error: Assigned data predict(x, na.action = na.pass, ...) %>% unname() must be compatible with existing data.` Also says existing data has 52 rows and assigned data has 41 rows. Any idea why that was different for me? And second, I will have multiple players, so where in the process/which variable would I use `group_by()` in? Thank you!

Comment: @ZachEllenthal Hi Zach, your issues are maybe because of some conflict with other packages. Try starting a fresh session and also loading `broom`. In the case of multiple players I will update the post now.

Comment: @ZachEllenthal I have added an update for multiplayers. Please check. I hope that helps you :)

Comment: Really appreciate your help! Still trying to get past the error message in `broom::augment`, even opened a new session and loaded in just `tidyverse` and `broom`. But if I can get past that, I think I can understand the rest of the solution you've laid out.

Comment: @ZachEllenthal So, you are having the issue running the code only with data in this post or are you using another data?

Comment: @ZachEllenthal Try installing the last version of `broom`.

Comment: Still just trying to run the data exactly copied & pasted from your post. I have have `broom` 0.7.0 installed right now, which according to what I'm looking at appears to be the latest version.

Comment: @ZachEllenthal Also could you please use this command on your console `sessionInfo()` and check the version of our packages!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221056/discussion-between-zach-ellenthal-and-duck).